# Learning Ruby: Making infinite dimensional array via block abuse

Tags: ruby, block

Somebody tell me what's going on here:

```
a = [0,1,2]
a.each {|x| a[x] = a}
```

The result is `[[...], [...], [...]]`.  And if I evaluate `a[0]` I get `[[...], [...], [...]]`.  And if I evaluate `a[0][0]` I get `[[...], [...], [...]]` ad infinitum.

Have I created an array of infinite dimensionality?  How/Why should this possibly work?

Comment: Why not? at position a[x] you find a, on which you can call a[x] again, etc., etc. Dimensionality always has also to do with orthogonality. This premise isn't given here.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with blocks. `a = []; a[0] = a; a[1] = a; a[2] = a` will have exactly the same result.

Comment: Using blocks you can actually (not quite) create an infinite dimensional array `blk = proc { |i| Array.new(10, &blk) }; a = Array.new(10, &blk)`.  This causes a SystemStackError though as Ruby can't handle infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you've modified every element in `a` to reference the list itself. The list is recursively referencing itself:

```
a[0] # => a
a[0][0] # => a[0], which is a
a[0][0][0] # => a[0][0], which is a[0], which is a
...
```

(`# =>` is a Rubyism for "this line evaluates to")

Depending on how you look at it it is not infinite. It's more or less just like a piece of paper with the words "please turn over" written on both sides.

The reason that Ruby prints `[...]` is that it is clever enough to discover that the list is recursive, and avoids going into an infinite loop.

By the way, your usage of `each` is a bit non-idiomatic. `each` returns the list, and you usually don't assign this return value to a variable (since you already have a variable referencing it, `a` in this case). In other words, your code assigns `[0,1,2]` to `a`, then loops over `a` (setting each element to `a`), then assigns `a` to `a`.

Comment: Ah... I see.  I don't think I've ever played with a language where you could do this.

Comment: @John: You can do this in almost any language. Including C, C++ (using explicit pointers or references), java, C#, python and many others.

Comment: Ah... I see.  And I'm starting to feel kinda dumb.  In retrospect, this all probably should have been obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a self-referential data structure. The a[x]=a puts a's pointer in a[x].